# How to sort two types of menus one based on Id and other normal to make it smooth moving to pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I have this website http://dryadavbhatta.com.np/, my menu is id based to scroll on the page for menus except for publication and forum page, So How can I sort my menu smooth when moving from publication to education or other like moving from home to others menu except for last two menus?

Comment: `sort my menu smooth` - not sure I understand the requirement

Answer (score -1):

Publication and Forum are two completely different pages... There is no way to animate that page change unless you move them into the single page application the rest of your site is under.

So basically, take the code for those two pages, put it in the original page and then the same way you performed smooth scrolling between every other section apply that to publication and forum.

Comment: Can I get information on why the downvote? I feel I did a half decent job on a high level explanation of what needs to happen to get into a position to be able to animate between the pages.